# Unity и извлечение Assets

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Кратко опишу суть дела: есть проект что лежит на GitHub

- https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/FPSSample

Он свободен для копирования, (но я так понимаю не ввесь ибо в нём использовались платные Assets из Assets Store, но так же использовались стандартные) 
И у меня возник вопрос могу ли я "извлечь" и импортировать для своих проектов все что есть в проекте? (Все сугубо в образовательных целях)

Сначала попробовал взять что нужно посредством использования Exporting packages, но это оказалось не очень хорошей идеей, поскольку структура у проекта сложная...

После прочтения всего раздела Asset packages в документации Unity, возник вопрос, могу ли я как то получить хотя бы список того, что было импортировано? Или возможно есть "нормальный" способ скопировать нужные материалы?

Обмовлюсь речь идёт о том, что было скачано из Assets Store (то бишь это по большей части полезные инструменты или материалы в разработке)  например как этот

- https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/fullscreen-camera-effects/post-processing-profiles-98845

Буду благодарен за советы или ссылки на подобный но решенный вопрос (искал, но найти не удалось). В общем буду рад за любую помощь.

Comment: По идее, при нормальной организации хранения файлов - все сторонние ассеты лежат в папке plugins по папкам соответствующим именам ассетов) а всё что лежит снаружи в других папках - это уже самописные обёртки плагинов.

Comment: Да, частично некоторые лежат там, но это точно не все, ибо к примеру я нашел ещё один сугубо в другой папке, что была внутри папок самого проекта. Я так понимаю какого-то +- простого извлечения нет?